# MediaPlayer e Thread

Tags: java, android, thread

Boa noite,

Tenho uma activity na qual eu reproduzo um sino x vezes, durante t tempo, e para isso uso um MediaPlayer dentro de uma Thread, conforme abaixo:

```
public void tocarSino(final int repeticao, final long intervalo,final int audio, final Context ctx){
          Thread timerSound = new Thread(){
              public void run(){
                  try {
                      for (int i=1; i<=repeticao; i++) {
                          MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, audio);
                          mediaPlayer.start();
                          sleep(intervalo);
                      }
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
          };
          timerSound.start();
```

}

ocorre que ao voltar da tela dessa Activity, o som ainda pode estar tocando, e então o usuário pode entrar numa outra Activity, onde pode ver os sinos disponíveis e testá-los. Nesse momento, como posso recuperar a Thread que estava sustentando o toque anterior e encerrá-la para que o som dos sinos na tela de testes não sobreponha em uma "cacofonia"?

NT: No exemplo de código acima me interessa que o sino repita sobrepondo o toque anterior por se tratar do mesmo arquivo de audio e para criar o efeito desejado. O problema é quando outra activity é chamada, com recursos de audio também, sem que o som dessa activity tenha encerrado com a Thread.

Obrigado

Comment: Faça isso num [bound service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi assim:
Declarei o MediaPlayer como global e adicionei ao onPause o seguinte código

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    if ((timerSound != null) && (timerSound.isAlive())){
        timerSound.interrupt();
        timerSound = null;
    }
    if((mediaPlayer != null) && (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer=null;

    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Mas ainda gostaria de saber recuperar uma Thread iniciada por uma Activity à partir de outra Activity.
Att.